# How to change Azure RM deployment name when deploying through Azure Portal link?

Tags: azure

When deploying a template [through Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-app-frameworks/#azure-portal), i.e. by following the link:

```
https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates%2Fmaster%2F{template name}%2Fazuredeploy.json
```

All deployments created this wah are named **Microsoft.Template** (and subsequent ones **Microsoft.Template_1**, **Microsoft.Template_2**, etc.) in the Deployments section of the portal:

[image: Azure Portal deployments]

Is it possible to customize the name (either by modifying the template, or provide a different name when deploying)?

Guessing, I tried adding `name` at the root level of the `azuredeploy.json`, but it gets refused with a wrong syntax message.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible from the Portal. I tested modifying the URL in the portal, and also after validation.

If you modify the URL the portal redirects to the Marketplace.

https://portal.azure.com/#create/**test**/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates%2Fmaster%2Fvm-disk-performance-meter%2Fazuredeploy.json

After the template was validated, I could modify the URL to https://portal.azure.com/#create/**test** and the deployment still gets created as Microsoft.Template

The Template itself also does not impact the deployment name. If you need to change the deployment name you may need to deploy from PowerShell or API

Comment: I appreciate your comment and your guessing, but if anything, given the example call structure, I would rather expect the following syntax for the API call: `https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/parameter1/<value1>/parameter2/<value2>/uri/<uri>`

Comment: The portal.azure.com is just a wrapper for the ARM deploy API which has the syntax https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourcegroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/microsoft.resources/deployments/{deployment-name}?api-version={api-version}

Comment: So are you suggesting `https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/deployments/myDeployment/uri/<uri‌​>` would work? Well, it doesn't.

Comment: No I am not suggesting that. I do not think you can change the deployment name from the portal...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today. If a deployment is in progress, we increment the count to Microsoft.Template_n. If a deployment has completed, we reuse the Microsoft.Template deployment name. (Source: I am the developer who built the template deployment experience in the portal)

I can easily make a change to use the {template name} you highlighted in the link as the deployment name. Or if you prefer @techraf's idea of supplying the name via parameters post a feedback request here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal and we will prioritize against other requests.